# How to pass in SQLServerDataTable object to JPA native query

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I am trying to pass in a SQLServerDataTable as a Parameter to a JPA native Query.

```
@Query(value = "Select u FROM #{#entityName} u with (nolock) INNER JOIN :listTable pt on pt.PhoneNumber = #{#entityName}.PhoneNumber WHERE EntityType = :entityType", nativeQuery = true)
Collection<Result> findAllByEntityList(@Param("listTable") SQLServerDataTable listTable, @Param("entityType") Integer entityType);
```

I get the following exception:

```
  nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not determine a type for class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataTable
```

How do I resolve this error Please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Spring JPA/Hibernate current implementation does not yet support passing in SQLServerDataTable as a Param.

I got around this by doing the implementation at the JDBC layer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Brian Antao's answer above there's some nice code for a JDBC implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575529/how-to-pass-table-valued-parameters-from-java-to-sql-server-stored-procedure)

And if you'd like to inject a Spring datasource bean you can read how to configure it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa)

Which will provide easy access to your datasource, like so:

```
SQLServerPreparedStatement statement = (SQLServerPreparedStatement) dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(ececStoredProc)
```