# In NamedStoredProcedureQuery want to set type as SQLServerDataTable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sql-server-2008

In `NamedStoredProcedureQuery`  want to set SQLServerDataTable

using NamedStoredProcedureQuery in spring boot and not able to set TT object as a parameter and getting type cannot be null exception

```
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "TT_UserHierarchyList", type = SQLServerDataTable.class)
```

It is working for the Wrapper class like Integer,Double,String...etc.

Have tired to set an entity and SQLServerDataTable.

while  creating
Query query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getChangedFarmers");

It is throwing Type cannot be null it is throwing.

Is it possible to set `type=SQLServerDataTable`?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Spring doesn't yet support `SQLServerDataTable` as a type, so code like this:

```
parameters = {
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "ParameterName", type = SQLServerDataTable.class)
}
```

Will throw an exception like:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null

So the solution is to implement your call to the stored procedure at the JDBC level.

There's some nice code for a JDBC implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575529/how-to-pass-table-valued-parameters-from-java-to-sql-server-stored-procedure)

And if you'd like to inject a Spring datasource bean you can read how to configure it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa)

Which will provide easy access to your datasource, like so:

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

SQLServerPreparedStatement statement = (SQLServerPreparedStatement) dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(ececStoredProc)
```